# Fluent Validation - How to remove default error message

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation, .net-7.0

I have a project with .NET 7 and try using Fluent Validation. My validation is as below:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Number)
.Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
.Must((model, number, context) =>
{
    var (isValid, isFirstMessage) = IsValidNumber(model.Unit, number);

    if (!isValid)
        context.AddFailure(nameof(model.Number),
         isFirstMessage 
       ? "My first message"
       : "My second message");

    return isValid;
})
.WithMessage(_ => string.Empty);
```

I use `.WitMessage(_ => string.Empty)` because if I don't do this, the Fluent Validation gives me a default message as below:

> "My validation message",
>
> "The specified condition was not met for 'Number'."

But I don't want any default message so with my way it gives 2 messages :

> "My validation message",
>
> ""

How can I remove that second fluent message? I want to show my validation message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context.AddFailure()` is used to add multiple error messages for the same rule.

For your case, you should use [Custom message placeholder](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html#custom-message-placeholders) if you use the `Must` method.

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Number)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
    .Must((model, number, context) =>
    {
        var isValid = IsValidNumber(model.Unit, number);

        if (!isValid)
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("ErrorMessage",
             "My validation message");

        return isValid;
    })
    .WithMessage("{ErrorMessage}");
```

Alternatively, you can implement a [custom validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html#writing-a-custom-validator) as below:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Number)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
    .Custom((number, context) =>
    {
        var isValid = IsValidNumber(context.InstanceToValidate.Unit, number);

        if (!isValid)
            context.AddFailure(nameof(Model.Number),
             "My validation message");
    });
```

Reference: [Custom validators](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html)

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mQmgzQ)

Comment: @Fildor's answer is pretty straightforward and simple if you only need to return a single error message/no other validation that requires to return different messages.

Answer (score 2):

As to my knowledge, this should already have the desired behavior (as of [Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77270965/2) of the question):

```
RuleFor(x => x.Number)
.Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
.Must((model, number, context) => IsValidNumber(model.Unit, number))
.WithMessage("My validation message");
```

Comment: It's my fault that my question is a bit incomplete. In fact, the IsValidNumber method returns another value, and this value helps me choose which of two different messages to use.
            if (!isValid)
                        context.AddFailure(nameof(model.Number),
                            isFirstMessage
                                ? "My first message"
                                : "My second message";
this isFirstMessage value return from IsValidNumber

Comment: Ok, in this case, you need to follow one of the solutions in @YongShun 's answer. I'll leave this one here for people that in fact do not have this additional requirement.